# Combine CTE along with an IN, in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions, common-table-expression, postgresql-10, sql-in

So I have this simple query in PostgreSQL 10.

```
with bunch_of_things as (
    select vans_id from shoes where adidas_id = 1
)

select * from vans where vans.id in (bunch_of_things) ;
```

I am getting an error `column "bunch_of_things" does not exist`

I know I could put the first select inside the parentheses of the second query, to define the IN part

But since I will use the results of the first query multiple times in the same transaction, I dont want to do the same query multiple times.

So how can I make the IN work along with a CTE?

(And if this is not possible, how can I get the results of a query once and use them multiple times in a transaction?)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name of the CTE is like a table so you should do a select

```
with bunch_of_things as (
    select vans_id from shoes where adidas_id = 1
)

select * from vans where vans.id in (select vans_id from bunch_of_things);
```

There are several things however you need to take into account.

Firstly, `EXISTS` usually is better performance wise than `IN`

```
with bunch_of_things as (
    select vans_id from shoes where adidas_id = 1
) 
select * 
  from vans v
where EXISTS (
    select 1
    from bunch_of_things b
    where b.vans_id = v.id
)
```

Secondly, in postgres 10 and below CTE is a performance fence so postgres cannot optimize the query as a whole (this [might](https://www.postgresql-archive.org/CTE-optimization-fence-td6026861.html) change however). This may be helpful way to control the query execution in some cases and is definitely the thing you should take into consideration.

The alternative way to execute a query and reuse the results in a transaction is using temporary tables like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bunch_of_things (vans_id integer)
ON COMMIT DROP;

INSERT INTO bunch_of_things (vans_id)
SELECT vans_id FROM shoes where adidas_id = 1;
```

And then use the table as usual:

```
select * 
  from vans v
where EXISTS (
    select 1
    from bunch_of_things b
    where b.vans_id = v.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will always be slow because in PostgreSQL a CTE is a optimization fence.

You'll want something like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM vans
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT
    FROM shoes
    WHERE adidas_id = 1
      AND vans_id = vans.id
)
```

that will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I will use the nested subquery a couple of times. So is it still faster if I define/execute  it everytime  ? Thanks